# What is the concept behind the hyperparameter "splitter" in DecisionTreeClassifier by sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, decisiontreeclassifier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEqxx.png)
screenshot

- I think that "splitter=random" means to find random threshold w.r.t each selected feature and then select the best threshold out of all random thresholds.
- And "splitter=best" means to find best threshold w.r.t each selected feature and then select the best out of all best threhsolds.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/115359/55122

Answer (score 0):

Here I am going to give the references:

[sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) uses default value splitter='best'

[sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier) uses default value splitter='random'

And it is clearly mentioned in sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier:

Extra-trees differ from classic decision trees in the way they are built. When looking for the best split to separate the samples of a node into two groups, random splits(thresholds) are drawn for each of the max_features randomly selected features and the best split among those is chosen. When max_features is set to 1, this amounts to building a totally random decision tree.

***Now I hope you can clearly get the understanding of hyperparameter splitter='best' or'random'.***